# Rendering maze in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

So I have successfully created my maze by implementing Prim's algorithm. The result is stored in a 2D array of Cells where each cell has a north, south, east and west (which stand for the 4 different walls).

The part that I am really struggling with is rendering this in 3D using cubes. Each cube represents a wall and I only want to render the cube if that wall is there. Below is the current code I have, but it is not working correctly (results in too many cubes being drawn/non-existent maze).

Any help would be appreciated. If more information is required, please let me know and I'll post it asap.

```
void Maze::drawMaze(vector<vector<Cell> > maze) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (maze[i][j].south == 1) {
                glColor4f(0, .2, 0, 0);
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(j * 2 - 2, 0, i * 2);
                glutSolidCube(2);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
            if (maze[i][j].north == 1) {
                glColor4f(0, .2, 0, 0);
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(j * 2 + 2, 0, i * 2);
                glutSolidCube(2);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
            if (maze[i][j].east == 1) {
                glColor4f(0, .2, 0, 0);
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(j * 2, 0, i * 2 + 2);
                glutSolidCube(2);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
            if (maze[i][j].west == 1) {
                glColor4f(0, .2, 0, 0);
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(j * 2, 0, i * 2 - 2);
                glutSolidCube(2);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a print method that I got to show a correct maze, just can't figure out how to translate it into the proper opengl.

```
void Maze::PrintMaze(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 2*10; ++i){
        cout << "_";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        cout << "|";
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
            Cell c = maze[i][j];
            cout << (c.south == 0 ? " " : "_");
            if (c.east == 0)
                cout << " ";
            else cout << "|";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
____________________
| | | |_  | | |  _  |
|  _|_   _   _  | |_|
|      _|_  |_    | |
| |_| | |_ _  |_|_ _|
|   |  _ _  |_ _|  _|
|_|_|  _| |_|  _|  _|
|_     _ _  | |_  | |
| |_| |   |  _ _ _  |
|      _|_|      _| |
|_|_|_ _|_ _|_|_|_ _|
```

Comment: besides north,south,east,west is there any "flag" for `wall` or `NO_wall` ??

Comment: No. If n,s,e,w is 1, there is a wall. If it is 0 there is no wall.

Comment: from what i understand you are drawing the cube as if you are in the center, dont you have to draw it as if you are inside the actual maze ?

south `glTranslatef(j * 2 + 2, 0, i * 2 );`
north `glTranslatef(j * 2 + 4, 0, i * 2 );`
east `glTranslatef(j * 2 + 2, 0, i * 2 + 2);`
west `glTranslatef(j * 2 + 2, 0, i * 2 - 2);`

Comment: That did not work correctly either. Filled in almost the entire grid. I added more to my original post as well.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a cube to render a maze that's not built out of cubes. Your maze is built out of *squares*, not cubes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points:

- You put your camera position correctly to look at ZX plane?
- Your cube didn't have a too thick width? Try to do a thiner cube and use glScale to make it taller

**Edit**

Try this code:

```
void Maze::drawMaze(vector<vector<Cell> > maze) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (maze[i][j].south == 1) {
                glColor4f(0, .2, 0, 0);
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(j * 2 - 2, 0, i * 2);
                glScalef(1, 1, 0.25);   // Added here
                glutSolidCube(2);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
            if (maze[i][j].north == 1) {
                glColor4f(0, .2, 0, 0);
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(j * 2 + 2, 0, i * 2);
                glScalef(1, 1, 0.25);   // Added here
                glutSolidCube(2);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
            if (maze[i][j].east == 1) {
                glColor4f(0, .2, 0, 0);
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(j * 2, 0, i * 2 + 2);
                glScalef(0.25, 1, 1);   // Added here
                glutSolidCube(2);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
            if (maze[i][j].west == 1) {
                glColor4f(0, .2, 0, 0);
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(j * 2, 0, i * 2 - 2);
                glScalef(0.25, 1, 1);  // Added here
                glutSolidCube(2);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, the ZX plane is the flat plane that I'm drawing the maze on.

Shouldn't the width not matter at all? As long as I offset each cube by the same width there shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Yes, but for what I have looked it seems that you have let no spaces to see your maze. Your cube has the same dimension at each side, so, only at portals that you will draw a hole. At result, you will see only a big cube with some holes on it.

Comment: Hmm ok. I tried decreasing the thickness and increasing the scale (in terms of y to make them taller). However, now there is simply a gap between all of the cubes (as there should be). Not sure what to do now.

Comment: Interesting. That code seems to give every part of the maze except for the borders. Thank you very very much though. I guess my initial attempts were pretty close. Just needed to scale.

Comment: Verify your matrix (maze[i][j]) and make sure that, at border, there is a wall on it.